# Need help identifying a shower/tub valve

Tags: plumbing

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pics]

[image: Pic3]

Hey guys I need some help to identify this valve. This is a condo I recently purchase. The previous owner apparently loved his trim so he took all the parts in the shower with him and left me a naked valve. If anyone can tell me how to get a replacement trim kit that fits this valve that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you can see it written on there with a model or make it is going to be difficult to find an exact replacement. (The left hand valve looks like it has writing stamped on it). Delta, Pfister are all I can think of as popular enough - your local Hd/W store might have generic repair kits. Or you can replace the whole thing.

Comment: Looks like the previous owner took the caulk, too. Is there an access panel on the other side of that wall which would let you get at the valve from behind?  Because it might be cheaper to replace the valve with a "builder basic" valve and trim kit from a big box store than buy trim (the most expensive part) for a decades-old unit.

Answer (score 0):

That is 100% for sure a Moen shower valve.